# Mod Rewrite and Include issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, include

I've googled for some mod_rewrite tutorials, but couldn't figure out how to solve my specific problem regarding the way I created my site with includes.

I've an index.php and in this file there are several includes like `index.php?s=events` will include `events.php` and so on.

If I use this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z_]+)$ index.php?s=$1 [L]
```

it will result that www.mydomain.com/events just shows the events.php itself, not with the "skeleton/framework" `index.php` around it, like it should be. So it just loads the specific included file.

My target is to call `www.mydomain.com/events` for example to show the whole `index.php?s=events` page.

Comment: I see no issue in your RewriteRule. Does requesting index.php?s=events directly give the correct page?

Comment: The only issue is that only "events.php" will be loaded and not "index.php?s=events".

Answer (score 0):

Try putting slash before URL into the RewriteRule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z_]+)$ /index.php?s=$1 [L,NC]
```

I added NoCase flag to get rid of capital letters in the regexp.

Comment: Still only loads the file "events.php" and not "index.php" including the events.php

Comment: @Vay no, I mean if you try in the browser? Maybe, you php is incorrect and not .htaccess